# How to best express this extension method for serializing / deserializing types

Tags: c#, serialization, extension-methods

I have the two following extension methods:

```
public static object DeserializeFromXmlFile(this Type type, string FileName)
{
        try
        {
            using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(type);
                return ser.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
}

public static bool SerializeToXmlFile(this object obj, string FileName)
{
        try
        {
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FileName))
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                ser.Serialize(writer, obj);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Then the code that uses them:

```
SaveToFile(string LogFile, MyClass c)
{
    c.SerializeToXmlFile(LogFile);
}

MyClass LoadFromFile(string LogFile)
{
    return (MyClass)typeof(MyClass).(LogFile);
}
```

I don't like how `LoadFromFile` uses the Deserialize method, can I make it as nice as the Serialize usage (in `SaveToFile()`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure an extension method of `Type` is the way to go here.  You're not really "extending" the `Type` class.  You could make it generic instead:

```
public static T DeserializeFromXmlFile<T>(string FileName) where T:class
{
    try
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return ser.Deserialize(reader) as T;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return default(T); // is this really the right approach?  Just ignore the error and silently return null?
    }
}
```

Then the usage is

```
MyClass LoadFromFile(string LogFile)
{
    return DeserializeFromXmlFile<MyClass>.(LogFile);

    // or return {classname}.DeserializeFromXmlFile<MyClass>.(LogFile);
    // if the static method is defined in a different class.
}
```

Note that you have to include `<MyClass>` in the call since the compiler can;t infer generic type arguments by using return types.

Comment: Thanks, generics makes the syntax look much better. As for silently returning, I edited out logging and reporting for simplicity. Thanks.

Comment: Generics are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to simplify the interface and make the signature of the two calls the same. This would result in much clearer code.

```
MyClass LoadFromFile(string LogFile, MyClass c)
{
    return (MyClass) c.DeserializeFromXmlFile(LogFile);            
}
```

and get the method to do the necessary fireworks instead of the caller.

```
public static object DeserializeFromXmlFile(this object obj, string FileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            return ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not that good. "MyClass LoadFromFile(string LogFile, MyClass c)" or similar function would be required for various classes to be deserialized.